# Dynamic_cast with ambiguous target class

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I was just reading Stroustrup's new book. In  Chapter 22.2.2 he discusses a dynamic_cast issue.

The code I have written to test this myself is as follows:

```
class Storable  
{
public:
    int i;
    virtual void r() {};
    Storable()  
    {
        i = 1;
    };
};

class Component:public virtual Storable
{
public:
    Component()  
    {
        i = 1;
    };
};

class Receiver:public Component
{
public:
    Receiver()  
    {
        i = 2;
    };
};

class Transmitter:public Component
{
public:
    Transmitter()  
    {
        i = 3;
    };
};

class Radio:public Transmitter
{
public:
    Radio()  
    {
        i = 4;
    };
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Radio *r = new Radio();
    Storable *s1 = dynamic_cast<Storable*>(r);

    Component *c = dynamic_cast<Component*>(s1);  // this should be 0 but it is not!

    return 0;
}
```

Stroostrup explains that c should be a nullptr as it is not possible to know which version of Storable is being referred to.  However, I get it as being a valid pointer.

I would guess that Stroustrup is probably correct on this but I cannot see what subtly I have missed, can anyone else spot it?

Comment: "class Component:public virtual Storable" - try removing virtual keyword here and see what happens ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance ).

Comment: @MateuszKołodziejski Still nothing - the OP's example is a purely linear, single-inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: @Mateusz, It works fine without that as there is a distinct Storable to each component.  The issue is supposed to be that there is a shared Storable for both Components to the dynamic_cast does not know which one to use and returns nulptr.

Comment: @Angew without any virtual methods this would not be a polymorphic class type and thus dynamic cast would not be able to downcast

Comment: @msam I was referring to virtual inheritance, not to a virtual member function.

Comment: @Stefan Ah yes indeed - you are not doing any multiple inheritance here. Nevermind then.

Comment: Did you mean for Radio to derive from both Transmitter and Receiver?

Comment: @Sean, Yep - have a look below at Angew's answer to be question of how can I most easily embarrass myself on a forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see ambiguity there. Have you transcribed the example correctly? Quoting C++11, `[expr.dynamic.cast]`§8 (using `dynamic_cast<C*>(v)`):

> ... if `v` points (refers) to a public base class subobject of the most derived object, and the type of the most derived object has a base class, of type `C`, that is unambiguous and `public`, the result points (refers) to the `C` subobject of the most derived object.

Your `v` is `s1`, which points to a `Storable` subobject of a most-derived object of type `Radio`. There's only one base class subobject of type `Component` in `Radio`, and it's public, so the dynamic cast should succeed, as it does.

It would be amgiguous if `Radio` was derived from `Receiver` as well; perhaps you missed that?